# Internal Server Error with Heroku Deployment of Django App

Tags: python, django, heroku, server, internal

I'm getting an Internal Server Error when going to url of Heroku App. There is a syntax error in the log, but I can't figure out if that's the problem. Can someone help me decipher this a bit more?

Link to app: https://gogolf.herokuapp.com/
Link to github: https://github.com/averyethomas/GoGolf

```
Averys-MacBook-Pro:gogolf averythomas$ heroku logs --app gogolf
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797537+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-09-28 14:31:51 +0000] [7]     [ERROR] Error handling request
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797551+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797548+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-28T14:31:51.637045+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797554+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = middleware_method(request)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797556+00:00 app[web.1]:     if (not    urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797555+00:00 app[web.1]:   File     "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 72, in process_request
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797557+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 614, in is_valid_path
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797549+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797560+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 489, in resolve
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797559+00:00 app[web.1]:     resolve(path, urlconf)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797552+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 87, in get_response
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797561+00:00 app[web.1]:     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797562+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 338, in resolve
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797563+00:00 app[web.1]:     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797564+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 367, in url_patterns
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797565+00:00 app[web.1]:     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797566+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 361, in urlconf_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797567+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797569+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797570+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797571+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797572+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797574+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797575+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797576+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797577+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797578+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797580+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/gogolf/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797581+00:00 app[web.1]:     url(r'^', include("golfApp.urls")),
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797582+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 28, in include
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797583+00:00 app[web.1]:     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797584+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797586+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797587+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797588+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797589+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797590+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797594+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/golfApp/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797591+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797592+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797595+00:00 app[web.1]:     from golfApp import views
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797593+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797598+00:00 app[web.1]:     print request.user
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797597+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/golfApp/views.py", line 18
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797600+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797599+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797601+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797603+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797602+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797605+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 359, in urlconf_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797604+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797607+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797606+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._urlconf_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797608+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797610+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797613+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797609+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797611+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797612+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797623+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.application(environ, start_response)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797614+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797616+00:00 app[web.1]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797622+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 119, in __call__
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797624+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797626+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.get_response(request)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797627+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797628+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797629+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 239, in handle_uncaught_exception
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797630+00:00 app[web.1]:     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797631+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 361, in urlconf_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797634+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797633+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797635+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797632+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797637+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797639+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797640+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797638+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797641+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797642+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797644+00:00 app[web.1]:     url(r'^', include("golfApp.urls")),
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797643+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/gogolf/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797649+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 28, in include
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797654+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797651+00:00 app[web.1]:     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797653+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797656+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797657+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797652+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797658+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797659+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797660+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797662+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797663+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/golfApp/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797664+00:00 app[web.1]:     from golfApp import views
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797665+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/golfApp/views.py", line 18
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797667+00:00 app[web.1]:     print request.user
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797669+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
2015-09-28T14:31:51.797668+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2015-09-28T14:31:51.800594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gogolf.herokuapp.com request_id=9d7c00ba-4c8d-41c7-bdf9-89a01b00a735 fwd="172.72.60.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=244
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first error message says: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

This looks like you are trying to deploy your Python 2.X based Django app in a Python 3 environment.

Comment: But note that OP shouldn't be trying to print in a view anyway. Unpredictable things can happen if you do. Use the logging commands.

Comment: Yep, I totally agree :)